# Writing nvarchar to a text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode

I have a problem with writing in a text file. Everything works fine when my text is ASCII:

```
DECLARE @OLE INT
DECLARE @FileId INT
DECLARE @File VARCHAR(max) = 'D:\test.txt'
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(max) = N'no problem when writing in english!'

EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject',@OLE OUT
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE, 'OpenTextFile', @FileId OUT, @File,2,1
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @FileId, 'WriteLine', Null, @Text
```

But nothing will be appeared in the file when my text has Unicode characters:

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(max) = N'من نمایش داده نمیشم'
```

I also tried `sp_OASetProperty` but that did not work ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754356/sql-create-xml-how-to-set-unicode-utf-8#answer-44759655)):

```
EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty @OLE, 'Charset', 'UTF-8'
```

Any idea to fix this or using other T-SQL procedures?

Comment: If you want UTF-8 instead of UTF-16, VBScripters use the "ADODB.Stream" object. (I've never used it inside of SQL, though and sp_OACreate is new to me. [SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/104406/) would be my first choice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Scripting.FileSystemObject documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx), the [`CreateTextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84).aspx) method takes a Boolean value to create a Unicode file. You could change the T-SQL code to use that method instead of `OpenTextFile`.

EDIT:

Below is an example using `OpenTextFile` per Tom's comment. I change the iomode value in your original code from 1 to 8 to match the documentation and added the close and destroy in case your full code is missing those important tasks.

```
DECLARE @OLE INT;
DECLARE @FileId INT;
DECLARE @File VARCHAR(max) = 'c:\test.txt';
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(max) = N'من نمایش داده نمیشم';

EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject',@OLE OUT;
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE, 'OpenTextFile', @FileId OUT, @File,8,1,-1;
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @FileId, 'WriteLine', Null, @Text;
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @FileId, 'Close';
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @FileId OUT;
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE OUT;
```

Comment: [OpenTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278834(v=office.14).aspx) does have a similar argument. BTW—NVARCHAR means UTF-16 and Unicode in the context of FileSystemObject also means UTF-16. The important part, though, is VBScript strings are also UTF-16 so passing NVARCHAR values to FileSystemObject function is the right parameter type. For the output, indicating Unicode will result in a UTF-16 encoded file.

Answer (score -1):

```
EXECUTE  @HR = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream',  @OLE OUTPUT

EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty    @OLE,    'Type',    2                    
EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty    @OLE,    'Mode',    3                    
EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty    @OLE,    'Charset',  'Windows-1256'   
EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty    @OLE,    'LineSeparator',    'adLF'
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod         @OLE,    'Open'  
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod         @OLE,  'WriteText',  NULL,   @String  
 
--Commit data and close text stream
 EXECUTE sp_OAMethod  @OLE,'SaveToFile', NULL, @FileAndPath, 2  
 EXECUTE sp_OAMethod   @OLE,  'Close'
 EXECUTE  sp_OADestroy   @OLE
```